# MKAnnotation doesn't show corresponding icon

Tags: ios, mkannotation

I used custom icon as an annotation in my map.
There are about 200 pins.

In the emulator, my map looks like this image.

[image]

However, in my device, there are some red points annotation which are near my userLocation.
Just like the below image showed.
[image]

I am guessing that it is a problem of some kind of runtime problem causing by speed, is it?
What shall I do to fix this problem?

I am using two classes

ViewController.m

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id    
      <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
   return [kmlParser viewForAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

KMLParser.m

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)point
{
// Find the KMLPlacemark object that owns this point and get
// the view from it.
for (KMLPlacemark *placemark in _placemarks) {
    if ([placemark point] == point)
        return [placemark annotationView];
}
return nil;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
{
if (!annotationView) {
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [self point];
    if (annotation) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *pin =
        [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation   
        reuseIdentifier:nil];
        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WaterStation"] ;
        CGRect resizeRect;
        resizeRect.size.height = 40;
        resizeRect.size.width = 40;
        resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
        [img drawInRect:resizeRect];
        UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        pin.image = resizedImage;
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        pin.animatesDrop = YES;
        annotationView = pin;
    }
}
return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code where return the `MKAnnotationView` for the `MKAnnotation`

Comment: Not sure why the images are not showing up at all, but it seems extremely wasteful to create a new image for every annotation, given that they're all the same... I'd recommend either resizing the image in a graphics program and including the correctly sized version in your bundle, or creating the resized version *once* and caching it as a property of your delegate. Besides: You should be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, so that you can create retina images.

Comment: I'll do the stuff you recommended. I find out that if I first set my location away from the annotations, then I moved back after a while, they would show up properly.

Comment: Another suggestion: Instead of using MKPinAnnotationView, use a plain MKAnnotationView (the MKPinAnnotationView subclass tends to ignore the image property since it's designed to show the standard red/green/purple pins only).  You'll have to comment out animatesDrop as well.

Comment: @Anna I have tried to changed it to MKAnnotationView. It did work!

Comment: Anna write that up as an answer! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating an `MKPinAnnotationView`, create a plain `MKAnnotationView`.

The `MKPinAnnotationView` subclass tends to ignore the `image` property since it's designed to show the standard red, green, purple pins only (via the `pinColor` property).

When you switch to `MKAnnotationView`, you'll have to comment out the `animatesDrop` line as well since that property is specific to `MKPinAnnotationView`.

---

A separate point that is not causing the image display problem but can affect performance is what @omz mentioned in the comments:

You don't need to programmatically create a re-sized image *every time* an annotation view is required:

- As @omz said, you can just add an already-resized image to your bundle and just do

  ```
  pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WaterStationResized"];
  ```

  instead of all that CG stuff (since your image is basically a constant).  This would be the best and simplest improvement here.
- If you know all your annotations will use the same image, you could also eliminate the `for` loop and just create and return an annotation view right there.  Remember that as-is, that `for` loop executes *every time* the map view asks for a view for *each* annotation.
- The code looks a bit convoluted so it's not clear if the `if (!annotationView)` is actually ever `YES`.  You might want to confirm this since this seems to be your caching mechanism.
- Instead of doing your own caching, you can also let the map view do it for you by making use of `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ItemAnnotationIdentifier];But the mapView isn't in the same class as the annotationView.

Comment: What you can try is call the dequeue in the class that is the map view delegate and if the dequeue returns nil, then call kmlparser's viewForAnnotation.  Make sure to set a non-nil reuseIdentifier if you decide to use the dequeue approach.  Also: if the dequeue returns a view (not nil), make sure to update its annotation property to the current annotation.